# Returned hashmap values are null

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I am restricting myself to just to the part of the question where I am going wrong.       I have an array of double values; I put all the values of the array which are non zero into  the hash map but when I am trying to display the values in my hashmap I get null values.
Help needed.I have not been able to figure out if this  has got something to with Java Collections.

The Map is created outside the for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<aray.length;i++) {
    if(aray[i]!=0) {
        //non zero array values get divided by some random number not too big number.  
        aray[i]=aray[i]/somenumber;
        hashmap.put(i,aray[i]); 
        System.out.println(hashmap.get(i));

        //if I display aray[i] its a non zero number but hashmap.get(i) is returning null values.  
    }
}
```

Comment: show how are you getting elements out of the map.

Comment: You've restricted it too much. [Create a SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem to get immediate and useful feedback. Specifically, we'll need to see where the map is created and how you're getting values from it.

Comment: Any chance that your "i" which you use to extract the values in hashmap.get(i) happens to be out of range of numbers you assigned values to?

Comment: No the values are perfectly below the numbers assigned;As I said I can print the array[i] but the hashmap.get(i) is returning null

Comment: That's still not enough. It isn't Correct (Compilable). Did you read the link? Not only are there three undeclared variables, there's also a missing ')'. Further, when I correct these errors and run the code you've posted, it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Did you new up the hasmap, I don't see that in your code...please post the full code so we can see what your hashmap variable is.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me.

### Program

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        final Integer somenumber = 2;
        final Integer[] aray = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, 42,};
        final java.util.HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashmap = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for(Integer i=0;i<aray.length;i++) {
            if(aray[i]!=0) {
                //non zero array values get divided by some random number not too big number.  
                aray[i]=aray[i]/somenumber;
                hashmap.put(i,aray[i]); 
                System.out.println(hashmap.get(i));
                //if I display aray[i] its a non zero number but hashmap.get(i) is returning null values.  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
user@host:/tmp$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_20
user@host:/tmp$ javac Test.java 
user@host:/tmp$ java Test 
2
2
1
1
0
0
-1
21
```

No null values anywhere, as expected. I don't see any way the map would be returning nulls, since you've just added the value.